# Deleting a static class instance of QWidget type causes invalid pointer error

Tags: c++, qt, static, qt5

I was trying to make a singleton class by sub-classing QWidget and exporting a static class instance. However, trying to delete such an instance causes a crash. Why?

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>

using namespace std;

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
  public:
    static MyWidget *get_instance(){ static MyWidget instance; return &instance; };
};



int main
(
  int argc,
  char **argv
)
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );
    MyWidget *widget = MyWidget::get_instance();

    QWidget *parent_widget = new QWidget;
    widget->setParent( parent_widget );
    delete parent_widget; //crashes 

    return app.exec();
}
```

Running the piece of code above produces the following error messages. I did not include the bakctrace message which is too long to be allowed to displayed in this post.

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-jon'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-jon'
*** Error in `/home/shouheng/tmp/build-exp_main-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/exp_main': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000006030c0 ***
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're confused by this.  When you call `delete parent_widget` then `parent_widget` will delete all of its children and so on recursively.  But the widget returned by `MyWidget::get_instance()` isn't allocated using `new` -- hence the error.

Comment: Use qt way when delete a qobject  : `parent_widget->deleteLater()` instead of `delete parent_widget`

Comment: @tunglt This will not solve the issue since it will still try to `delete` an object that's not allocated on the heap with `new`.

Comment: @tunglt That would only defer the problem to a later point, more precisely to [when the event loop has started](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater), but then exactly the same problem occurs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete the parent widget, `delete` will be called on all its children, thus on the pointer to your singleton object, that hasn't been created using `new`, i.e. is not allocated on the heap:

```
static MyWidget instance;
```

To avoid this, just *un-parent* the singleton object, this way

```
widget->setParent(nullptr);
```

before calling delete on `parent_widget`.

Answer (score 2):

Qt transfers/handles ownership with parent.

So when you do

```
widget->setParent( parent_widget );
```

`parent_widget` will delete `widget` in its destructor (except if its parents changes before).